# Big Query Timeout Errors

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to insert data into big query tables and the request fails with this message:

> Post URL: read tcp IP_ADD:22465-\u003eIP_ADD:443: read: connection timed out

Could some one explain what is timing out exactly? Retrying does not fix the problem.

Comment: Could you please share with us the code you are using to make the insertion? Is it a streaming type of insertion?

Comment: Yes, it is  a streaming insertion.

Comment: With this [Streaming Data into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) article in mind, can you provide a code sample that produces this behavior and/or some complete logs of these requests?